# SKSpriteNode causes scene to be grayed out

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I create a SKSpriteNode and add it to the scene graph inside my SKScene:

```
// First I set a white background
self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
let cannon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cannon")
cannon.size = CGSizeMake(32, 160)
cannon.position = CGPointMake(size.width / 2.0, 0)
self.addChild(cannon)
```

This is "cannon.png", which is in my Images.xcassets (my bad, it's a very ugly cannon):

[image]

If I add it I get a totally gray scene, while if I comment the last line (so I don't add the sprite to the scene), I get a white background.

Comment: Have you changed the size of GameScene.sks or just simply add the code in a new SpirteKit project?

Comment: @WangYudong I created a new project, and then modified the line where I create the scene in GameViewController: I don't load it from the sks file, instead I just call a plain init method ("let scene = GameScene()").

Comment: Try my answer below and tell me if you have any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `size` of your `scene` before adding the nodes to it. Modify your init method like this and problem will be solved.

```
let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
```